# MapReduce Freezes at 99%

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have this problem with a very simple hadoop program which progress to 99% of reduction stage and then freezes. The input is a very lite file ~50 lines of text, the output should be very straight forward key-value pairs of Id's and their frequencies.

I have increased mem allocation inside mapred-site.xml to ~6Gig.

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx6024m</value>
</property>
```

I tried to examine the log files but they are all empty, nothing is written to them. Please suggest what could be wrong with this?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so the problem was fixed when I started using newer Job & Configuration classes. Till now I was using legacy code which seem to be causing lot of errors. So I guess my advice here is to use the latest hadoop libraries & not the deprecated ones.

Sad that some of the hadoop books still teach with legacy classes & APIs.-- **Do not use them!**

Comment: Besides it looks like Hadoop does not make deprecated methods by @Deprecated annotation. So all the legacy methods look perfectly legit..... However they are highly inconsistent...